# Are Session and EntityManager the same?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, hibernate-session

New to JPA and was wondering if `Session` (Hibernate) and `EntityManager` are the same thing or not? As both of them basically allow you to manage and search for entities in the relational database.

Also any good source materials on the 2 would be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: For future readers: *Java Persistence API (JPA)* is [now known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence#Jakarta_Persistence_3.0) as [*Jakarta Persistence*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/).

Answer (score 1):

There might be some more slight differences between those 2 but the main concept is the following:

- `Session` belongs to `org.hibernate` package, and is an interface of `Hibernate`. This belongs to a specific library that provides implementation of JPA, namely `hibernate`.
- `EntityManager` belongs to `javax.persistence` which belongs to Java EE and not some external library. This is the package that the specifications for `JPA` are provided from `oracle`. Every library that wants to implement `JPA` in java ecosystem must follow these specifications from this package.

If you have `Hibernate` configured in your project, then for example the `entityManager.persist(obj)` will invoke the `session.persist(obj)` through the delegate architecture that hibernate has and then the `sessionImpl.persist(obj)` of hibernate will be invoked which will do the actual job.

**To sum up**:

- `session` is just an API for `Hibernate` only.
- `EntityManager` is an API provided by Java EE for `JPA`.

*JPA is also implemented by another library `eclipselink`. In the future a requirement may arise and you may need to switch to use `eclipselink` library instead of `hibernate`. This is why you should construct your project to be based on `entityManager` instead of some library specific API.*

Comment: @BasilBourque I agree it was unclear.  Just updated answer.